# Checking if innerHTML exceeds width or height of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div with a fixed width and a fixed height.

The contents how ever might exceed this, so I am wondering is there a way in Javascript to calculate if the content exceeds the fixed dimensions?

An example would be like this:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">

 A sentence that exceeds the width!

</div>
```

In the above case it does exceed the width. How would this be achieved in Javascript?

Comment: You'd have to wrap the content in another element, in order that JavaScript could target/access that node and work out its width/height compared to the parent's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a parent for your content:

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
 <div id="parent">
 A sentence that exceeds the width!

</div>
</div>
```

now you can get width and height of the parent and compare it with your main div:

```
var h = document.getElementById("parent").offsetHeight;
var w = document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOM properties](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml) of the div and text nodes. If you can wrap the text in a `<span>` element, it seems like it will be easier to work with the dimension properties.

html

```
<div id="container">
  <span>A sentence that exceeds the width!</span>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

js

```
var cont = document.getElementById('container');
var spn = cont.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
//alert(cont.clientWidth);
//alert(spn.offsetWidth);

if(spn.offsetWidth > cont.clientWidth) {
    alert("content exceeds width of parent div");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bn2Uc/2/